# Putting data in embedded Table View in UIView container

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

It's this case again:

[image]

I wish to fill the prototype cells with the names of the friends selected in the UIPickerView over there. I have programatically filled the picker with the string representation of my Player object data, and set its properties using the delegate functions.

The "New Game Friends View" you see here has its own viewcontroller subclass, as has the table view, which I attempt to embed into a UIView on the "New Game Friends View". The table view IS an instance of my *WHGFriendTableViewController* class. I know this because this function does not throw any exceptions:

```
- (IBAction)addBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    WHGFriendTableViewController* tabView = (WHGFriendTableViewController*) [[self childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSInteger row = [friendPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    [[tabView selectedFriends] addObject:[[self friendList] objectAtIndex:row]];
    [[tabView tableView] reloadData];
}
```

Now the problem is: while the function above does not throw any exceptions, it still does not work. It appears that nothing really happens when I insert the objectAtIndex:row into the NSMutableArray selectedFriends (which is a property) in the table view's view controller.

This:

```
NSLog(@"New length: %d", [[tabView selectedFriends] count]);
```

prints 0 after inserting the new object. I have no idea why. Printing the count of [self friendList] gives three, just as I expect. The reloadData message does not make anything appear in the table view.

Any ideas why I cannot insert new data into the table view with my code, when this seems to be working with no exceptions whatsoever? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you alloced & init your `NSMutableArray` selectedFriends?

Also have you set the `dataSource` and `delegate` of your table view?

Comment: Thank you so much! I had simply forgotten to alloc and init it... Wow, so much for 3 hours of debugging. Thanks to you it's now working :)